# What caused Flash and Actionscript to become irrelevant?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, frontend, interactive

At first glance this question may seem like I'm looking for opinions or a discussion, but hear me out. While I'm sure everyone has their own opinion of which tools are best to use, there have got to be some factual reasons why Flash's popularity faded away.  I'm sure there were certain events and inventions that caused people to prefer other tools, and I'm dying to know what those events are. So I am looking for answers that are based on facts and events. All I can gather from the research I've done and the projects I've seen is that Flash used to be really popular for creating interactive media or cartoon-like movies, but now it's not.

The background story to this question is that over the past few months I've been creating a project with Adobe Animate and Actionscript for a college class. It's been fun and I find that Animate is extremely useful. I would like to think that the skills I've learned will be useful in the future, but I've heard from several different people that Flash is pretty much irrelevant now and I can't figure out why.

I know that front end developers are using Javascript and HTML/CSS for most things, and I do understand some of the advantages. Javascript programs seem to have more open-source availability, and of course no one wants to pay a subscription for Adobe products forever. But what I don't get is what replaced the visual aspect of the "stage". Something as simple as drawing a circle could become hard really quick, or tedious at the least, if you're just using code alone. And if you draw two or more objects, you have to worry about their relative positions. Flash makes that super simple by allowing you to just drag them to where they need to be. But once again I imagine it would be really boring to have to use trial and error to position things solely with code.

So are the Javascript coders using something similar to Flash for their animations that I'm just not aware of, or are they really just using code alone? If they are just using code, WHY would they give up the stage aspect of design?

Comment: Because Flash went down the tubes. Lack of support on mobile, slow load times, lack of SEO, etc.

Comment: This is not a question for Stackoverflow.   Flash on the web is indeed legacy now, and it should be (why have a plugin from a third party running software in the your browser when it isn't necessary?).      AIR however is still relevant and your skills can be used there.  For web delivery though, don't use flash,  find a good JS framework and use that (CreateJS / Pixie etc.)

Comment: ah, yeah, forgot to mention people's general dislike for plugins. Again, not really about the language or the feature set that Flash provides compared to HTML5. (also notice the suggestion to use a JS framework... there was no need for this in AS3, but in JavaScript development it's pretty much a must)

Comment: _**"I've heard from several different people that Flash is pretty much irrelevant now and I can't figure out why."**_ that's simple... They don't need to use it so they don't understand why it's useful to others. Flash is many things to many people. A Disney animator won't diss Flash but a JS/CSS expert might. @epascarello replied first but I doubt he's a Flash user, he'll tell you "lack of support on mobile" but won't tell you that Flash outputs Android & iOS apps (using AIR) anyways... Skills are skills to apply elsewhere. DJ skills = rhythm in animation. AS3 skills = Other coding languages

Comment: @VC.One When flash started to decline there was no way to export to mobile. Why flash died was the fact that most people blocked flash to get rid of the annoying ads and the long list of security vulnerabilities that came with it. Than later on browsers disabled Flash plugins making sites unusable.  Flash lost the PR game. I agree that Flash did a lot of things nice and I once did code in it.

Comment: @epascarello _**"Flash lost the PR game"**_ sums it up nicely & is probably nearest thing to a correct answer for this Question's title.

Comment: "Why flash died was the fact that most people blocked flash to get rid of the annoying ads and the long list of security vulnerabilities that came with it." Not true... only a tiny percentage of online users blocked Flash --mostly those who frequented tech news sites where Flash security vulnerabilities were almost guaranteed to be sensationalized. Look up the vulnerability history of your favorite browser sometime...

Comment: also, companies were not overly concerned with those who disabled Flash, just like they're not currently overly concerned with those that disable JavaScript. It's a small percentage, and those that do it get a nice message telling them to enable it back to view the website, which they very often do. so... non-issue for two reasons.

Comment: Purely money! Flash created a platform where developers could create one source code and deploy programmed web multimedia and animations across all browsers and devices. Microsoft tried to copy Flash with Silverlight. Google didn't support Flash (include in google searches) because it cost them too much to do so. Apple blocked Flash because Flash could create apps. Swf's could behave exactly like apps and packaged apps could be sold directly to users. Apple blocked Flash at the massive expense of all web business and user experience so they could make endless millions through their app store.

Answer (score 10):

Politics, sadly. Flash was/is superior to HTML5 in almost every way (explained below), but there were a number of non-technological factors that ushered in its demise. Below are a few that come to mind:

1) Ads. This was the way most people grew to recognize Flash content; if it was flashy and annoying, it was probably Flash. This was unfortunate as it was not the technology itself that was the problem, but the use of it. (the fact that Flash was used so much for this type of content says something about how effective Flash was at creating this type of content).

2) Full Flash websites/games. Again, this was not so much a problem with Flash, but those who used it to create the content. Often devs will produce content on machines that are significantly faster than the average user's, and do most, if not all, testing locally.

3) The 1st iPhone was quite slow compared to those that exist today, and it was slow compared to a majority of computers as well. It is no surprise then that a technology that specializes in multimedia, running in a virtual machine, may have problems running on such a device; however, to say this would be to say something negative about the device, and rather than do that a 100% of the blame was put on the technology. The average consumer's experience with my previous points made this tactic easy to pull off.

4) Adobe gave up after losing the PR battle. There were many things they could have done to save Flash, such as: not dropping Android support, not dropping Flex support, not dropping Flash Builder support, and not ignoring the dwindling Flash engineer community. There is no reason why the iPhone could not run Flash today (and run it well), and there is no reason why Adobe couldn't create a transcompiler to convert content; I already did this (flash api, full as3 language support, e4x, etc.), but it's not open source as of yet. If one engineer could do this, they certainly could have!

5) Overblown publicity of Flash vulnerabilities. Critical vulnerabilities are found in programs all the time, browsers, operating systems (yes, even OS X), etc. But due to the growing discontent for Flash in the general public, issues found in Flash were covered as if Flash was the only program that was exposing people to vulnerabilities.

Technology: Is/was Flash tech superior? Absolutely, HTML5 was actually a huge step back, and here is why:

1) Flash was stable. If you got your app to work, it would almost be guaranteed not only to function exactly the same in all browsers and operating systems, but also to look identical as well. Want to develop an HTML5 app? Either use a javascript library to fix all/most browser inconsistencies, or welcome yourself to a debugging nightmare. So, of course, you add that abstraction layer, but now what happens when you still have an issue? Well, now you have to dig through that layer..

2) Flash/AS3 does it better. Want to have pixel perfect text across all devices? Flash, yes. HTML5, nope. Want REAL classes, typing, Vectors, weak references, interfaces, objects as keys, namespaces, private variables, asset embedding, etc. ? Flash, yes. HTML5.. while it's possible to create a compile-to-JavaScript language to pull most of this off, now you have to deal with that output when you're debugging. How about complex, nested, animations? How easy/fast is that to do in Flash... Sure, editors can be made to output the equivalent in HTML5, but most will not stream like Flash did, and will have severe limitations compared to what Flash can do.

3) The Flash API. The Flash API was well documented, powerful, and pretty simple to use. Compare this to the joy of searching online looking at compatibility lists and vendor prefixes for HTML5.

4) todo... there is quite a bit more.

HTML5 is better only in the fact that it is 100% open (and it's not a plugin, which people tend to dislike). The SWF specification is open, and there was an open-source Flash player (the Tamarin project); so, it is not as if Flash was completely closed like some would suggest; personally, I would trade the openness of HTML5 for stability and consistency any day.

However, if openness is one's primary concern, then one would probably view the step backwards in capability and efficiency as worth it.

BTW: I actually write all my HTML5 and NodeJS code in Flash/AS3 and compile to HTML5/JS. I can still use Flash for debugging (and as my gold standard if you will), which is fantastic..

Comment: There is no correct answer to this but I upvoted the effort before question is closed (deleted). At least this way you didnt write for nothing. PS: Asker really should have just done their research on the web...

Comment: One feature that I miss is the visual editor in Flash. You just don't have that for HTML 5 games anymore. (Maybe Godot engine if exporting to HTML5). Great post